# Play! Framework - return multiple list to template

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, twirl

I have 3 classes and I wanna return 3 lists to template which use in Form
my db is MongoDB

```
def addCourse = Action.async {implicit request =>
  val teacherCollection = db.collection[BSONCollection]("Teacher")
   val courseColl = subjectCollection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor[Subject].collect[List]()
   val teacherColl = teacherCollection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor[Teacher].collect[List]()

    courseColl.map { course =>
      val sam = teacherColl.map{teacher=>
        teacher
      }
    Ok(views.html.Course.addNewCourse(course,sam,Course.form))
   }
  }
```

template code :

```
   @(subject:List[models.Subject],teacher:List[models.Teacher],myForm: Form[models.Course])
```

I have got an error : Type mismatch expect List[Teacher] , actual Future[List[Teacher]]

What am I gonna do?

note : if i put Ok(views...) to val sam map, compiler show an error,it's sounds like async error becouse "async" will be red

```
 Error:(59, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 /app/controllers/School.scala:59: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
  required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

Comment: It is not obvious what you're trying to accomplish. `val sam` is a `Future[List[Teacher]]` because your `map` function on it is pointless. If you moved the `Ok` inside that `map` function, you may have progress, but you'd have other compiler errors. Also, `courseColl.map` will give you `courses =>` but it seems to be named as though it is a single item instead of a list. Also, I'm only presuming that your 'colls' are Futures - I have no idea what db library you're using, so I can't replicate the code myself. Try explaining the code more, and people may be able to help.

Comment: please check post edit

Comment: i have been fixed this problem with flatMap

Comment: If you've fixed it, you can post the answer below and accept it :) If not, I will look into making an example this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem with flatMap

```
courseColl.flatMap { course =>
  teacherColl.flatMap { teacher =>
    semesterColl.map { semester =>
      Ok(views.html.Course.addNewCourse(course, teacher, semester,    Course.form))
    }
  }
}
```